# How do I choose between valid regular expressions - example from eloquent javascript, chapter 9

Tags: javascript, regex

[Chapter 9 of Haverbeke's *Eloquent Javascript*](http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html) contains the following regex example:

```
console.log(
  "Hopper, Grace\nMcCarthy, John\nRitchie, Dennis"
    .replace(/([\w ]+), ([\w ]+)/g, "$2 $1"));

//   OUTPUT:
// → Grace Hopper
//   John McCarthy
//   Dennis Ritchie
```

However, I am not sure why he uses square brackets or why he has a space after the `\w`. The following regular expressions seem to produce identical output:

```
console.log(
  "Hopper, Grace\nMcCarthy, John\nRitchie, Dennis"
    .replace(/([\w]+), ([\w]+)/g, "$2 $1"));       // Spaces removed.

console.log(
  "Hopper, Grace\nMcCarthy, John\nRitchie, Dennis"
    .replace(/(\w+), (\w+)/g, "$2 $1"));           // No brackets or spaces.
```

JSFiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/aq53t1qL/)

**TO SUMMARIZE**

1. From a performance or best-practices perspective, are there any differences among the three regular expressions given above?
2. If so, what are they?
3. If not, how should I distinguish between them when making coding decisions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[\w ]` allows for spaces in the names which you can't see because of the sample data.

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a35tqnee/) where I added spaces into the first set of data to show how the original differs.

Version one allows for word characters or spaces.
Version two allows for word characters or well just word characters because teh brackets only include `\w`.
Version three allows for just word characters.

The difference between two and three is that two gives a list of allowed characters that happens to just contain one entry while version three doesn't give a list.  If I had to guess I'd say tree might perform better than two but I don't know for sure.

Expert from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) explaining the []'s:

> Character set. This pattern type matches any one of the characters in the brackets, including escape sequences. Special characters like the dot(.) and asterisk (*) are not special inside a character set, so they don't need to be escaped. You can specify a range of characters by using a hyphen, as the following examples illustrate.
>
> The pattern [a-d], which performs the same match as [abcd], matches the 'b' in "brisket" and the 'c' in "city". The patterns /[a-z.]+/ and /[\w.]+/ match the entire string "test.i.ng".